# Is $dS \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ equivalent to Clausius theorem?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If we integrate over a cicle we have
$$
0 \ge \oint \frac{\delta Q}{T}
$$
because $S$ is a state function. On the other hand we can prove $dS \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ starting from Clausius theorem. So I suppose the two are equivalent. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thank you. Therefore, $dS \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T}$ can be considered a statement of the second law of thermodynamics? No more nor less than Clausius, Kelvin, etc.? (of course supposing to know the meaning of symbols in the equation)

Comment: I think some independent research would be well applied here. Even Wikipedia states clearly: "The Clausius theorem is a mathematical explanation of the second law of thermodynamics." A search for related statements in Google Scholar or Google Books, for example, would provide vast amounts of peer-reviewed discussion of the topic, if Wikipedia isn't credible enough.

Comment: @Chemomechanics In Wikipedia about Clausius theorem I read "is a mathematical explanation of the second law", "provides a quantitative formula for understanding the second law" and "is in a sense a weaker condition than the Second Law itself" but I can't find that it is equivalent to second law. Anyway if my question is stupid I apologize.

Comment: Yes, it is a mathematical statement of the 2nd law.